# dgrid ColumnHider, CompundColumns, and ColumnReorder does not work together

Tags: dgrid

I have a grid that uses these extension and they do not seem to work together.  More specifically the `CompoundColumns` does not work with `ColumnReorder` but, the `ColumnHider` does not work without it.  I am also using `ColumnSets` but there are examples that show ColumnSets, and ColumnReorder together in the src code under test.

```
 var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, CompoundColumns, ColumnSet, Selection, Selector, 
 Keyboard, Editor, ColumnHider, ColumnResizer, ColumnReorder, Pagination]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about `ColumnHider` requiring  `CompundColumns` is not true. Check out [this test](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.1.0/test/extensions/ColumnHider.html)

The order in which you add the mixin is important. The `ColumnHider, ColumnResizer` etc., must be before `CompoundColumns`, since it extends `ColumnHider` and `ColumnResizer` methods.

Try this order

```
 var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, Selection, Selector, Keyboard, Editor, ColumnHider, 
 ColumnResizer, ColumnReorder, CompoundColumns, ColumnSet, Pagination]);
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  The grid does not display the data at all.  If I remove columnhider and compoundcolumns it will display the data but I lose the ability to hide and show columns.  I can add back in the ColumnHider (before ColumnResizer) but the popup does not display correctly without having compound columns.  Maybe this is a bug in the version I am using due to the use of ColumnSet?  The example you provided does not use ColumnSet.  and I have seen other examples but none use ColumnSet and the ColumnHider.  This combo needs the CompundColumns which must come before the ColumnHider

Comment: popup? Would it be possible for you to share the complete code or setup a jsbin or something which I can take a look at the behaviour. If you look at this http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/extensions/CompoundColumns.html, the 3rd grid has both compoundcolumns and both ColumnHider and ColumnResizer with ColumnSet.